# Usage compared to last year

Tags: sql, date, sqlite

I have a table that contains two columns - date an amount (usage). I want to compare my usage with last year's

**Data**

```
Date        Amount
01-01-2015  23
02-01-2015  24
03-01-2015  19
04-01-2015  11
05-01-2015  5
06-01-2015  23
07-01-2015  21
08-01-2015  6
09-01-2015  26
10-01-2015  9
[...]
01-01-2016  30
02-01-2016  19
03-01-2016  5
04-01-2016  8
05-01-2016  15
06-01-2016  27
07-01-2016  19
08-01-2016  21
09-01-2016  24
10-01-2016  27
[until today's date]
```

The sql statement should return results up to today's date and the diff should be a running total - the amount on a day in 2016 minus the amount on the same day in 2015, plus the previous difference. Assuming today is Jan 10, the result would be:

```
Day         Diff
01-01-2016  7   (30-23)
02-01-2016  2   (19-24+7)
03-01-2016  -12 (5-19+2)
04-01-2016  -15 (8-11-12)
05-01-2016  -5  (and so on...)
06-01-2016  -1
07-01-2016  -3
08-01-2016  12
09-01-2016  10
10-01-2016  28
```

I can't figure out to do this when the data is all in one table...

Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, keeping a running total is one thing SQL (of any kind) isn't very good at unless you use stored procedures (which sqlite3 does not have natively). In MySQL, you can also use @variables to overcome this limitation, but, in general, you will need to use an external procedural language here.

Comment: You can get a running total by joining the table to itself on the days equal to or less than the date and doing a sum(). You get the year to year comparison by joining one year's running sum to the next year's running sum by day and month.

Comment: @Rabbit could you show me how?

Comment: This is not one of the [supported date formats](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html).

Comment: @something_new what have you tried so far? I'm not in the habit of posting full code when someone hasn't shown an attempt at solving the problem themselves.

Comment: @Rabbit I'll have a go at it and I'll post the results here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT t1.date Day,SUM(t2.Diff) FROM
amounts t1
INNER JOIN
(SELECT amounts.date Day, amounts.amount-prevamounts.amount Diff
FROM amounts inner join amounts prevamounts 
ON amounts.date=date(prevamounts.date,'+1 years')) t2
ON t2.Day<=t1.date
group by t1.date;
```

demo here :
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/9bd4c/41

Comment: Doesn't give the running total. According to other users, might not to do it just with sqlite

Comment: Did you check the sqlfiddle demo I made ? it returns exactly the requirement. what is missing or mistake please?

Comment: It does not return the requirement exactly. Please check the results in the OP again. Your first row is correct, everything else after it is wrong.

Comment: @AtheerMostafa The column Diff is supposed to be a running total, not just the monthly difference

Comment: @something_new  sorry I didn't notice the accumulative total.
I corrected the solution now.
Would you recheck and update your vote ... thank you for you comment

Comment: @Rabbit , yes I didn't notice this accumulative sum .. it is not fixed in all rows results and you can check the fiddle.
Thank you for your clarification.

Comment: @AtheerMostafa Yes, it's correct now. Marked as correct. Thanks you!